# Intersect is not providing any results using EqualityComparer

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am misunderstanding how to implement EqualityComparer and Intersect. I want to understand sets using c# and linq but the below code produces no results. This is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{



public class objTest : EqualityComparer<objTest>
{
    public int index { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public override  bool Equals(objTest x, objTest y)
    {
        return x.index == y.index;

    }
    public override int GetHashCode(objTest obj)
    {

        return obj.index.GetHashCode();
    }


}
 static void Main(string[] args)
{

    List<objTest> L1 = new List<objTest>();
    L1.Add(new objTest { index = 1, name = "ALAN" });
    L1.Add(new objTest { index = 2, name = "bill" });
    L1.Add(new objTest { index = 3, name = "clive" });
    L1.Add(new objTest { index = 4, name = "dave" });
    L1.Add(new objTest { index = 5, name = "ewan" });

    List<objTest> L2 = new List<objTest>();
    L2.Add(new objTest { index = 11, name = "ALAN" });
    L2.Add(new objTest { index = 12, name = "bill" });
    L2.Add(new objTest { index = 13, name = "clive" });
    L2.Add(new objTest { index = 14, name = "dave" });
    L2.Add(new objTest { index = 1, name = "ALAN2" });
    //THIS HAS NO RESULTS
    var L3 = L1.Intersect(L2);

}
}
```

Could someone tell me why L3 has no results ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference an instance of a class implementing `IEqualityComparer` in `Intersect`. Like so:

```
        public class objTest 
        {
            public int index { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
        }

        class eqcomp : EqualityComparer<objTest>
        {
            public override bool Equals(objTest x, objTest y)
            {
                return x.index == y.index;

            }
            public override int GetHashCode(objTest obj)
            {

                return obj.index.GetHashCode();
            }


        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<objTest> L1 = new List<objTest>();
            L1.Add(new objTest { index = 1, name = "ALAN" });
            L1.Add(new objTest { index = 2, name = "bill" });
            L1.Add(new objTest { index = 3, name = "clive" });
            L1.Add(new objTest { index = 4, name = "dave" });
            L1.Add(new objTest { index = 5, name = "ewan" });

            List<objTest> L2 = new List<objTest>();
            L2.Add(new objTest { index = 11, name = "ALAN" });
            L2.Add(new objTest { index = 12, name = "bill" });
            L2.Add(new objTest { index = 13, name = "clive" });
            L2.Add(new objTest { index = 14, name = "dave" });
            L2.Add(new objTest { index = 1, name = "ALAN2" });
            //THIS HAS RESULTS :)
            var L3 = L1.Intersect(L2, new eqcomp());
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to use an external comparison, mrtig has answered.

**If you wanted `objTest` instances to compare themselves:**
You are overriding the wrong `Equals` and `GetHashCode`. You should be overriding the `Equals` that takes one parameter and compares it against `this`. You should not be implementing `EqualityComparer`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    public class objTest
    {
        public int index { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object other)
        {
            objTest o = other as objTest;
            return o != null && o.index == index;
        }
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return index.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<objTest> L1 = new List<objTest>();
        L1.Add(new objTest { index = 1, name = "ALAN" });
        L1.Add(new objTest { index = 2, name = "bill" });
        L1.Add(new objTest { index = 3, name = "clive" });
        L1.Add(new objTest { index = 4, name = "dave" });
        L1.Add(new objTest { index = 5, name = "ewan" });

        List<objTest> L2 = new List<objTest>();
        L2.Add(new objTest { index = 11, name = "ALAN" });
        L2.Add(new objTest { index = 12, name = "bill" });
        L2.Add(new objTest { index = 13, name = "clive" });
        L2.Add(new objTest { index = 14, name = "dave" });
        L2.Add(new objTest { index = 1, name = "ALAN2" });
        //THIS HAS NO RESULTS
        var L3 = L1.Intersect(L2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you ! I can see the difference now!

Answer (score 0):

You should implement `IEquatable<objTest>` instead of `IEqualityComparer<objTest>`.  The MSDN documentation for `Intersect` is misleading, as it instructs you to implement the latter, even though the examples implement the former.

Note that you should also override `Object.Equals` and `Object.GetHashCode` in this case. Something like:

```
public bool Equals(objTest other)
{
    return this.index == other.index;
}

public override bool Equals(object other)
{
    var o = other as objTest;

    return o != null && Equals(o);
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return index.GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: Actually he is implementing `IEqualityComparer<objTest>.GetHashCode`, which is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for your input - my understanding is much better!